# Domains & Subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdirectory

I set up a WordPress installation for a friend under a subdirectory on my site. I have set up his domain name to point to the subdirectory of the installation (and I have his domain name registered under my GoDaddy account). I can't figure out how to configure my GoDaddy account or the WordPress installation to use his domain name for all his webpage's addresses.

For example, I want his website to display `myfriendssite.com/about.php` instead of `mysite.com/friendswordpress/about.php`

I have tried editing the .htaccess files for both my main sites directory and my friend's directory to no avail (I don't know what I'm doing). Please help!

Comment: What happens when you go to myfriendsite.com currently?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache, you should configure a virtual host with the myfriendssite.com and point it to the correct directory.

Because you haven't provided any example of the config code, I cannot give you specific example but please read through the apache doc for virtual host and you should find what you need. Here's the [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

If you can post some sample of the relevant apache config, or specifics like sample domain and directories, I can help you more with a config example.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. I'm lost in the details here and can't really figure out what I need to do. I'm using my cousins website, (http://infinite-views.com/deckerandsons), for hosting and the subdirectory is the Wordpress install I'm trying to use with (http://deckerandsons.net). Would giving you the .htaccess file information from both the root and subdirectory folders be helpful? Thanks again!

Comment: yes, looking at the .htaccess will definitely help. You can just update your question and append it there.